# Installed nuget, but don't see the menu option Add Library Package Reference in tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I installed nuget using the extension manager in vs.net 2010 ultimate.

It re-started, and I still don't see the "Add Library Package Reference" menu in the tools menu.

**What could be the issue?**

I can only get to the powershell console and use nuget.

Library Package Reference is there in Tools, but it has only 2 options:

```
Package manager console
Package manager settings
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this may be the default. It's the same for me and I have Ultimate 2010 too...

When I open a solution file I get additional options "Manage NuGet Package for solution"

I do get options to manage NuGet packages when I right click on a Solution file in the solution explorer. I just have to have a solution loaded.

I assumed this was how it supposed to work as I've never seen it working any other way...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a solution/project open that supports it, you will only see those two options.